# Redux Thunk : redux thunk is not dispatching an action

Tags: reactjs

I am looking at thunk and trying to figure out how to implement an api call. It is not working so I have gone back to the very basics. When I click on the button in the console is showing dispatch is not a function.

i think the problem comes from applymiddleware cause when i comment it out the increment and decrement buttons , the error gone. What i did wrong?

```
const store = createStore(root,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(fetch), window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()

  ))
```

```
const Counter = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{props.count}</h1>
            <button onClick={props.increment}>+</button>
            <button onClick={props.decrement} >-</button>
            <button onClick={props.fetch} >Add</button>

        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    return {
        count: state.CountReducer.count,
        // item: state.CountReducer.item
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        increment: bindActionCreators(increment, dispatch),
        decrement: bindActionCreators(decrement, dispatch),
        fetch: bindActionCreators(fetch, dispatch),


    }
}
```

and here is the code of the thunk and reducer

```
export const fetch = () => {
    return dispatch => {

        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
            .then(response => dispatch(add(response.data)))
    }

}
export const add = (answer) => (
    {
        type: "ADD_DATA",
        payload: answer
    }
)
```

```
const initialState = {
    count: 0,
    item: []


}

export function CountReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    console.log("reducer");
    console.log("state");
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_DATA:

            return {
                ...state,
                item: action.payload
            }
        case INCREMENT_COUNT:
            return {
                ...state,
                count: state.count + 1
            }



        case DECREMENT_COUNT:
            return {
                ...state,
                count: state.count - 1
            }
        case GET_FETCHED_POSTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                item: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state

    }

}
```

Comment: are you wrapping your Counter component with the connect HOC?

Comment: Yes i did :   export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(Counter);

Comment: I don't see where you added the thunk middleware to the store when it was created. Your increment/decrement buttons also don't seem to use any asynchronous logic.

Comment: i added fetch in the middleware. const store = createStore(root,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(fetch), window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()

  ))

Comment: What middleware is fetch?

Comment: noo, i  added fetch function in the middleware, i saw it in the tutorials

Comment: Try  `const store = createStore(root, compose( applyMiddleware(thunk)`

Comment: Tutorial is incorrect. You need to add the thunk middleware to your store. https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#installation

Comment: Also, just an FYI, upgrading to/adding [Redux-Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) provides Thunk middleware ***AND*** the dev tools by default, and is even easier to setup than the older `react-redux`. (*It's developed by the same team that developed Redux and React-Redux, BTW, so it just works with all your existing actions and reducers*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code to create store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducer from './reducer';
const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];

const composeEnhancers =
  typeof window === 'object' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
    ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({})
    : compose;

const enhancer = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware));

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, enhancer);

export default store;
```

Comment: thanks very much. This worked for me, but now the problem is that i cant see datas on my screen